# WebappclassLoader and StandardclassLoader jar conflict

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, classloader

I'm having an issue I believe is due to Tomcat, but I'm not sure where to go because I'm not too knowledgeable on the subject

The problem is, I have a couple of projects that use log4j, and recently when starting the server I get the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@a9ae05] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
```

Doing some reading, I saw it pointed out that this was due to having several copies of the same jar. 
Now, I believe that this is Tomcat's fault. I made a second server in Eclipse and the new server boots fine, so that sounds like a problem with the server configuration in the messed up one.

So I assume my old Tomcat is loading a jar file and this causes a conflict, whereas the new one doesn't have this jar file to cause the conflict in its configurations? My question is; how do I go about finding the culprit jar or configuration error?

Comment: use a tool like jfind(http://jfind.sourceforge.net/) and give the conflicting class and give the directory to search as your old tomcat. This will show you if more than one jar contains the specified class. Then your job is easy as having to remove one of the duplicated jars.

Comment: Thank you - this was a useful tip. Very nice tool

Comment: Hi arnehehe, have you got the exact solution ? I am getting same above error with tomcat 6 but not getting with tomcat 8.

Comment: Hmm. Try seeing if your Tomcat 6 has a conflicting jar in its lib\ folder; that you also find in your .war's \WEB-INF\lib folder. Conflicting versions of the same library in your war's lib and your tomcat's lib has caused problems for me